# Applying paste() to a data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have a numeric data.frame that I would like to alter by pasting a `%` behind each element.

```
A <- data.frame(A = seq(1,10,1))
apply(A,1, function(x) paste0(A[x,],"%"))
```

This works fine, however if the data has decimal place, `apply` doubles each entry.

```
 B <- data.frame(B = seq(1,5.5,0.5))
apply(B,1, function(x) paste0(B[x,],"%"))
```

It works with `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)
B %>% mutate(B = paste0(B,"%"))
```

but I would like to understand why the apply solution fails.

Comment: Because you are subsetting by the value not the position. Try `B[1.5]` to see how the evaluator treats decimal subsets.

Comment: try `apply(B, 1, function(x) paste0(x,"%"))`

Comment: @PierreLafortune that makes sense, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
sapply(B,paste0,"%")
```

Since the data frame examples in the OP consist of a single vector, it may be useful to show that this works for a general dataframe:

```
B <- data.frame(x1 = seq(1,10,1), x2=seq(1,5.5,0.5))
sapply(B,paste0,"%")
#      x1    x2    
# [1,] "1%"  "1%"  
# [2,] "2%"  "1.5%"
# [3,] "3%"  "2%"  
# [4,] "4%"  "2.5%"
# [5,] "5%"  "3%"  
# [6,] "6%"  "3.5%"
# [7,] "7%"  "4%"  
# [8,] "8%"  "4.5%"
# [9,] "9%"  "5%"  
#[10,] "10%" "5.5%"
```